# jquery ajaxstart is not triggerred on the first load

Tags: jquery, ajax, backbone.js

Following is my code

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $(document).ajaxStart(function () { alert("start"); });

  // page render using backbone and fetching json through ajax call
  .....
}
```

This page is rendered by backbone using json data fetched from server. The page has buttons which perform additional ajax calls when clicked. On the page load, ajaxStart doesnt get triggered though the json data is requested/returned properly. Once the page is rendered completely, ajaxStart is triggered as expected whenever I click buttons to do other ajax calls. I was wondering why ajaxStart is not triggered on the first load and how would I fix this?

Thanks!!

Comment: Try binding the global handler sooner, take it out of `.ready`

Answer (score 3):

Most likely the ajax is starting before you bind your event. Try binding it sooner:

```
$(document).ajaxStart(function () { alert("start"); }); // outside of .ready
$(document).ready(function() {


  // page render using backbone and fetching json through ajax call
  .....
});
```

Comment: yep you are right working now for the first call also . Thanks